# JavaScript function expression

Tags: javascript, function

The following line:

```
var A = function def() {alert();};
```

Only A() invokes the function. def() does not. Why is it so? Isn't the left side a function delaration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the function expression the function name is primarily used for self-calling. IRL this feature is handy in case of anonymous functions and recursive calls, i.e.

```
(function def() {
    // ...
    def();
})();
```

Comment: Ok make sense. But why def() has no effect from outside in the question while it would have had if it were defined using "function def() {}"?

Comment: @CharlesW. This is because the name of function expression is not visible outside of it's scope.

Comment: Okay thanks! And is that also the reason why we can have many anonymous functions? Cause they are confined in their scopes so there's no conflict or ambiguity?